Group Convolution Weights in Pycaffe
I am trying to implement depth wise convolution in Mobilenet V2 in caffe.
I do this by setting the parameter in conv_param num_output to be equal to the groups param. 
Taking 112x112x96 input 56x56x96 output  with 3x3s2 DWCONV as one of the depthwise examples: 
When I extract the weights I notice that they are 864 bytes which corresponds to 3x3x96
I extract the weights by using pycaffe: 
weight = net.params['conv'][0].data
My question is how do I access the other group weights? Does caffe reuse the same weights when I initialize the weights using the weight filler param? 
